# Find the Area $A$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

My attempt:

> $A=\ln {e^2}-\ln 1=2$

Is this a correct answer?

Comment: Yes it is correct :)

Comment: :) @Thanks Lucas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. The area asked is an elementary application of integration. Specifically :

$$A = \int_1^{e^2}\frac{1}{x}dx=\big[ \ln(x)\big]_1^{e^2}= \ln(e^2)-\ln(1)=2\ln(e)=2$$

Comment: 2 seconds first :)

Comment: @gimusi I'm as fast as a Tommy-Gun !

Comment: I would like to thank each of you. I did each of you Upvote.+1,+1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is indeed

$$A=\int_a^b \frac1x dx = [\log x]_a^b \implies A=\log e^2-\log1=2-0=2$$

Comment: I would like to thank each of you. I did each of you Upvote. +1,+1)

Comment: Thanks, you could go with head/tails to accept an answer :)

Comment: Yes now it is hard to do this .. :) I want to accept both of you. :)

Comment: I've a lot of rep today, accept Rebellos! Bye :)